# Save EMGUCV VectorOfKeyPoint to XML and load again

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

Using EMGUCV, for C#, it is possible to save a Matrix to XML so it can be read later.
Being that VectorOfKeyPoint is a Serializable class, it can also be saved to a XML file.
Nonetheless, when it is open, this UnmanagedObject VectorOfKeyPoint is empty and can not be used.

Is it possible to do something in this way, meaning, in order to load the VectorOfKeyPoint from a XML and use it in the same way?

Nowadays, the working code, as explained in EMGU Wiki, but changed for a VectorOfKeyPoint:

[Parsing from/to XML](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#XML_Serialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to do it.

Instead of serializing the VectorOfKeyPoint itself (that won't work), one can serialize it's points.

eg.

Serializing:

```
VectorOfKeyPoint vectorOfKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
MKeyPoint[] keyPoints = vectorOfKeyPoints.ToArray();
(new XmlSerializer(typeof(MKeyPoint[]))).Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), keyPoints);
xmlKeyPoints = sb.ToString();
```

Deserializing:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlStr)); 
MKeyPoint[] arrayOfKeyPoints = (MKeyPoint[])(new XmlSerializer(typeof(MKeyPoint[]))).Deserialize(xmlReader);
VectorOfKeyPoint vectorOfKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
vectorOfKeyPoints.Push(arrayOfKeyPoints);
```